# Canvas DrawImage does not work on IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, safari

I have a canvas with an id called napkin. When I call the following function it is supposed to draw an image and the napkin canvas onto another canvas in memory. It works on every browser but IOS Safari. The operation does not seem to exceed the IOS memory cap for the canvas. I test this by calling k().toDataURL(). Any ideas?

```
function k() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var napkin = document.getElementById("napkin");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = picurl;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imgdata = new Image();
    imgdata.src = napkin.toDataURL();
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.drawImage(imgdata, 0, 0);
    return canvas;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the image has downloaded before youre trying to draw it to the canvas?

Comment: Yes because the image that returned canvas only contains the image, not the other canvas.

Comment: I'm also face the same problem., how to solve this issue

Comment: Are you sure k().toDataURL() is not returning a black image? That's what happens when it's out of memory. it returns a LARGE black image

Answer (score 7):

You need to wait for the image data to load before using it...

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    // do stuff here with img
};
img.src = picurl;
// not here
```